# Android emulator internet connection issues - real device works.

Tags: android, json, httpclient, httpresponse

I´m trying to get a JSON-Format text from a website. It works perfectly on my real smartphone, but it don´t works in the Android Emulator(4.0.3).
Checking Internet Connection is positive with this one:

```
ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Activity.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
```

That gives me empty result in my emulator, but I get something in my phone:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));

    inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
        if (inputStream != null)
            result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
```

Comment: can you post more code relating to the url?

Comment: using one code of the tutorials: https://github.com/hmkcode/Android/blob/master/android-http-get-json/src/com/hmkcode/android/MainActivity.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read through this, it should solve your problem:

http://www.gitshah.com/2011/02/android-fixing-no-internet-connection.html

Comment: thx typing "-avd <Emulatorname> -dns-server 8.8.8.8" fixed my problem!